# Plex installation doesn't give option to setup server

Tags: server, plex, mediaserver

Server Version#: 1.19.3.2852-219a9974e

I’ve just installed Plex Server on a Ubuntu VM following this guide [How to Install Plex on Ubuntu 20.04](https://linuxhint.com/install_plex_ubuntu-2/), I was able to get the server working but I don’t have any option to setup the server itself and when I go into the “YOUR MRDIA” section, I get a notice to download and install Plex Server.

[image]

I’m baffled about how this software works, to be fair I don’t get the “How Plex Works” nor “Server Setup” options, I get redirected to the main home screen.

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Go tot the actual Plex site and follow the info there not some third party site. I run Plex on Ubuntu it works well. https://www.plex.tv/

Comment: @David I have tried the Plex own documentation first (https://support.plex.tv/articles/200288586-installation/), but that also have the same result. I've tried installing on Ubuntu 20.10, 20.04 and 16.04 then I resort to this guide and I still can't figure out why it doesn't give me the option to setup the server and tell me to download and install Plex again. I will try reinstalling from scratch again.

Comment: After installing the plex server on Ubuntu did you go to the Plex site in a browser and finish the setup like it tells you to?

Comment: Yeah, it asked me to create an account so I did with Google and the redirection brought me back to the page on the post. I didn't prompt me for anything else.

Comment: Send a ticket to Plex support on their site. I do not think this is a Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Thanks, @David. I'll raise a ticket on there. I did post on their forums first but I got no response.

Comment: Update on this, the Plex support wasn't very helpful at this issue, they just ask you to talk to the community. But I've found the solution by looking at the configuration of the service; to access the server I must access the server over `localhost:32400`. If you're to use the machine IP like I did (`172.18.100.30:32400`) it won't let you access the server. I wish this was documented well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey so my problem was that I wanted to setup Plex on a remote dedicated Ubuntu server (the OS version is 18.04 LTS). And I got the same problem as the original poster. And I found a solution.

As noted by the original poster [here in their comment reply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321062/plex-installation-doesnt-give-option-to-setup-server#comment2254992_1321062), using localhost instead of the IP address worked for them. It turns out that this was the issue all along for me as well. Unfortunately, I obviously couldn't just replace the IP address w/ localhost because my plex server was remote. So I was stuck (or so I thought, as you'll see below).

Then I ended up uninstalling plex on my server (I used [this link](http://alice-at-ubuntu.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-completely-remove-plex-media.html) for that, including doing the last commands they mentioned) and then following this [guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-plex-media-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/) and it worked! The plex web app was able to identify my server. So yeah, that's the solution.

The reason it works is because of a crucial step in that guide that involves using an SSH tunnel in order to circumvent the problem where Plex apparently will only allow localhost connections in order to access the web app properly. Ctrl-F search the guide I linked for 'SSH tunnel' to find that step that I'm talking about. Basically you're tunneling your local computer to the remote server's localhost address when accessing the web app, and thus making Plex happy. Because as far as Plex is concerned, you're now accessing the web app through localhost.

Note: Accessing the web app w/ the SSH tunnel step in the guide was very slow for me. At one point, the web app seemed to be stuck loading, showing an eternal loading spinner. I purposefully disconnected and reconnected from my ssh tunnel connection and the web app to see if that would maybe fix it. It did, and then I was able to finish the setup process.

Also, after you finish the server setup, you don't need to use the SSH tunnel anymore. At that point, you should be able to just access the web app at `http://YOURSERVERIPADDRESS:32400/web` on your browser like normal.